# How to write an awk which reads a text and if it encounters a line starting with # (i.e. a comment line)?

Tags: shell-script, awk, scripting

It will add # followed by a space to the beginning of each following line until the end of the paragraph (paragraphs are separated with an empty line). The lines which already start with # are not modified
E.g. the following input

```
a b c
d e f
# g h i
j k l
m n o

p q r
s t u

# v w x
# y z 1
2 3 4
# 5 6 7
8 9 0
```

would be modified into

```
a b c
d e f
# g h i
# j k l
# m n o

p q r
s t u

# v w x
# y z 1
# 2 3 4
# 5 6 7
# 8 9 0
```

Comment: I think you need to fix your input ... don't add newlines to create next line, but format is as code. @msp9011, I think your edit is not what OP intended...

Comment: Please format question: remove unwanted empty lines, replace `/empty line separating these into paragraph/` with an empty line. When it looks as you want highlight it and click on `{}` Then fix the title: A title is not the start of a sentence, it is a summary of the question.

Comment: I'm confused. Why are `a b c`, `d e f` and `p q r`, `s t u` exempt? And you mean paragraphs are separated by **two** newlines, correct? Also, do you have to strictly do the whole thing in awk, rather than just using a shell function?

Comment: I understand it like that commenting starts from the first commented line in each paragraph. So after `g h i` and in second paragraph it doesn't start at all. OP says separated by *an empty line* or as you say two newlines is basically the same, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```bsh
awk '/^$/{comm=0}{if($1~/^#/){comm=1}else{if(comm){$1="# "$1}} print}' file
```

or same in long form:

```bsh
awk '
    # reset on empty line
    /^$/{comm=0}
    {
        if ($1~/^#/) {
            # start commenting lines when # found
            comm=1
        } 
        else { 
            # comment lines not starting with #
            if (comm){ $1="# "$1 } 
        }
        print
    }
' file
```

Comment: Please explain the downvote. This is working just fine.